# Are there any "War Of The Dead" maps

Tags: savage-worlds

In the **War Of The Dead** Campaign for Savage World there are no provided Maps in the PDFs. I have seen on the forum that **Daring Entertainment** intended to produce some for the encounter locations but I can't find them. Anyone know if they where produced?

Comment: I've e-mailed the developer and we'll see how they respond.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Summary: No, there aren't any.

Their response to my e-mail:

> Hey Brian,
>
> You're actually the first
>   to ask about the maps since June, as
>   the players at the Savage forums have
>   been creating their own as they
>   modified the adventures to fit their
>   group more.   Anyway, back in July we
>   had commissioned a cartographer in the
>   RPG industry with a good reputation
>   for producing RPG maps. As was his
>   standard fair, we gave him a down
>   payment on the final total that would
>   be owed. Unfortunately, the
>   inidividual (whom I won't name out of
>   remaining professional), took the
>   money, ceased contact with us, and
>   never produced the maps.   Since the
>   amount we gave him would constitute an
>   additional 15-20 pieces of interior
>   art for the print editions that
>   Cubicle-7 is releasing for us, we
>   haven't commissioned a new
>   cartographer at this stage. Those
>   we've talked to about it have similar
>   rates and want down payments as well,
>   or have significantly lower rates but
>   whose quality is . . . well, let's
>   just say it leaves much to be desired
>   for commercial product support.   So,
>   thanks to the fiasco with the
>   cartographer and the down payment that
>   was stolen, and the need to move
>   forward with Chapter Two and the print
>   edition of Chapter One, the maps have
>   not been released. Due to the fact
>   that we've had no requests for them
>   (outside of one or two initially)
>   since Chapter One released in June
>   (and have actually had requests "not"
>   to include maps and instead focus on
>   word count and other support), it
>   seems unlikely they will be released
>   at this stage.
>
> Regards,   Lee F.
>   Szczepanik, Jr.